# Joining 2 one to many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 3 tables but am getting some unusual results, having for example three records appear from bookid 1 as it is in 3 categories, how do I avoid this?The table structures are;

table = book
 - bookid
 - author
 - title

table = categoriesbooks
 - bookid
 - categoryid

table = category
 - categoryid
 - categorydesc

When I join the tables using;

```
SELECT book.bookid, book.author, book.title, category.categorydesc
FROM book
JOIN bookscategories ON book.bookid = bookscategories.bookid
JOIN category ON bookscategories.categoryid = category.categoryid
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I was hoping to get something along the lines of
bookid | author | title |categorydesc
1|        Bob |     mybook | Thriller
                          Horror

Comment: @Tom: You have to determine how you wise to combine the 3 records it will hit in categories (or which of the one to chose). You will most likely end up using a subquery, but again, you have to choose the algorithm before anyone can really help you with the SQL (unless we as the non-user, non-archetects are gonna start just making design decisions for you-- in which case, imho, crosses the lines between 'do my job' and 'i need help over this roadblock'.  SO is here for the later in case you were wondering)

Edit: What makes one category #1 and another one #2, etc.

Comment: @colinross Am I right in thinking that the subquery would be the more sensible way of doing it as I am going to expand this query into multiple one to many's eg; target user, etc. So, how do I make a subquery would have been a better question! Sorry for not being specific.

Comment: look the the specifics according to your rdbms (mysql in this case) but most of them allow using `( __subquery__ ) AS __alias__` where subquery is a fully qualified query and alias is how you reference it in the join (and in the select)  Google search should bring up thousands of examples...

Comment: @colinross Thanks, I will check it out, I'm sure it'll come in useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, use a group by bookid to limit the results to one row per book.
You can use group_concat to still see all the categories in a CSV list.

```
SELECT book.bookid, book.author, book.title, group_concat(category.categorydesc)
FROM book
JOIN bookscategories ON book.bookid = bookscategories.bookid
JOIN category ON bookscategories.categoryid = category.categoryid
GROUP BY book.book_id
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: the 'give a man a fish' answer, but literally retrieves an arbitrary category for books with multiple categories. Not really the 'best way to go' for any seriously structured application IMHO

Comment: @colinross, it does not retrieve an arbitrary category. It retrieves all categories in a comma separated list. Read the link.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, presuming you only want one record per book, that you want the first Category, and `categorydesc` is numeric, you'll need something like this (you may have to play around with the specifics)

```
select distinct b.bookid, b.author, b.title, (min)c.categorydesc
from book b
join bookscategories bc on b.bookid = bc.bookid
join category c on bc.categoryid = c.categoryid
```

If categorydesc is not always numeric, then what you need to do is write a `Where` clause which will essentially be a second select statement where you pull the lowest CategoryId for each distinct book.

Comment: On second thought -1 because this only ever returns one row, because of the `min()` aggregate function.

Comment: @Johan: You're right, I need to move the min().  But the theory is largely the same.  I'll work on the edit a little bit.