# How to Join Multiple Many to One Relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join three tables that have One-to_Many relationships with a single query, and I'm not sure how to define the joins. I have diagramed a sanitized version of the table structure below, with an example of the result I'm trying to achieve. Is this possible in SQL, and if so, how. If my goal is not possible, what other possible solutions are available?

Specifically, I am working with SQL Server. And I explored other answers, and the answer for [Joining 2 one to many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312239/joining-2-one-to-many-relationships) seems promissing. But I would like to avoid concatenating multiple results into a comma separated list

This is an example of the One side of the relationships. This is a table that stores Order data, I have trimmed it down to essentials concerning this question.

```
Order_Table
Order_ID Customer_ID
    1        1
    2        1
```

This is an example of one of the Many sides of the relationships. As you can see in this example, each One order can have Many Line Items.

```
Line_Item_Table
Line_Item_ID Order_ID
      1         1
      2         1
      3         2
      4         2
```

This is an example of the second Many side of the relationships. Each One Order can have Zero to Many Order Modifier codes.

```
Order_Modifier_Table
Order_Modifier_ID Order_ID
       1             1
       2             1
```

The result I am trying to achieve would look similar to this

```
Line_Item_ID Order_ID Order_Modifier_ID_1 Order_Modifier_ID_2
      1         1              1                   2
      2         1              1                   2
      3         2              NULL                NULL
      4         2              NULL                NULL
```

Comment: Take baby steps.  Start by joining Order_Table to Line_Item_Table.

Comment: I can handle that join. That's just a simple INNER JOIN.

Comment: You cannot have a variable column-set with static SQL, so Dynamic SQL is the only supported way to do this.

Comment: Where can I find information about how to write the needed dynamic SQL?

Comment: Do not write dynamic SQL. There is VERY rarely any need for it, it exposes potential security risks (SQL injection), is often quite messy (and hard to maintain), and does not take advantage of some SQL Server optimizations. I haven't written dynamic SQL in about 10 years, and I've done some pretty hairy SQL!

Comment: @Spikeh Static SQL is definitely preferred, where applicable, but Dynamic SQL works just fine when written correctly and is the best solution for certain requirements.  For instance, in this case, where the return column-set is not determined until run-time.  About 10% of the SQL that I write is dynamic and it is both secure and performant.

Comment: That said, I do agree that caution is warranted and a beginner should take extra care to insure that they are safe against SQL Injection in their dynamic SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain joins pretty fluently. If the database is complex, I always like to have a DB diagram lying around so I can work with it a bit quicker.

It sounds like you need to PIVOT here. I just threw this together as a "work in progress":

```
IF OBJECT_ID('LineItems') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE LineItems
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('OrderModifier') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE OrderModifier
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Orders') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Orders
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Customers') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE Customers
GO

CREATE TABLE Customers (
    Id          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Name]      VARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    Id          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    CustomerId  INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customers(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE LineItems (
    Id          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    OrderId     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE OrderModifier (
    Id          INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    OrderId     INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Orders(Id)
)
INSERT INTO Customers(Name) VALUES('Customer Name')

INSERT INTO Orders(CustomerId) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO Orders(CustomerId) VALUES(1)

INSERT INTO LineItems(OrderId) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO LineItems(OrderId) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO LineItems(OrderId) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO LineItems(OrderId) VALUES(2)

INSERT INTO OrderModifier(OrderId) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO OrderModifier(OrderId) VALUES(1)

SELECT
    li.Id   AS LineItemId,
    o.Id    AS OrderId,
    om.Id   AS OrderModifierId
FROM LineItems li
INNER JOIN Orders       o   ON li.OrderId   = o.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderModifier   om  ON o.Id     = om.OrderId
```

This produces the results below:

```
LineItemId  OrderId     OrderModifierId
----------- ----------- ---------------
1           1           1
1           1           2
2           1           1
2           1           2
3           2           NULL
4           2           NULL
```

We now need to PIVOT the Last column.

Comment: I just realised that the results you want are pivoted. That'll take a bit more work...

Comment: I was not aware of Pivoting. I'll go research. If you have any other information, it would be appreciated.

Comment: It takes me a little time to get my head around it. Just trying to work it out for you now :) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think I get the concept you've introduced me to. I found an article that gives a simple example of Pivoting. And you're right, this looks be exactly what I was looking for. Time to experiment. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query